# Creating a year-week column from distinct year and week columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, time-series

There's a data frame on which I want to perform time series analysis. The data frame contains distinct columns of year and week:

```
Year Week stateID values
2018  2     231     55
2010  3     231     92
2000  5     231     56
2018  2     321     55
2010  3     321     45
```

For performing analysis, I want to concatenate year week column to datetime object having the format Year-Week. i.e:

```
Year-Week stateID values
2018-2     231     55
2010-3     231     92
2000-5     231     56
2018-2     321     55
2010-3     321     45
```

How can I achieve it in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC,

```
df['Year-Week'] = df['Year'].astype(str) + '-' + df['Week'].astype(str)

df['Period'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'].astype(str) + '-' + df['Week'].astype(str) + '-' +'0', format='%Y-%W-%w').dt.to_period('W')
```

Output:

```
   Year  Week  stateID  values Year-Week                 Period
0  2018     2      231      55    2018-2  2018-01-08/2018-01-14
1  2010     3      231      92    2010-3  2010-01-18/2010-01-24
2  2000     5      231      56    2000-5  2000-01-31/2000-02-06
3  2018     2      321      55    2018-2  2018-01-08/2018-01-14
4  2010     3      321      45    2010-3  2010-01-18/2010-01-24
```

Comment: Hi, can you tell the use of "dt.to_period('M')", please?

Comment: @EishaTirRaazia Well, I created a dtype Period to represent a period range of a month.  dt is the datetime accessor to use special datetime methods such as to_period.  See this section in docs https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#overview

Comment: In this data set, I only have week wise data i.e: week 1-52, and year against week number. Will your method still work fine?

Comment: Week in data frame is basically referring to 'week of the year'

Comment: Yes, this is incorrect. I was thinking that week was month. `.dt.Period('W')`

Comment: Also when I use %y-%W it says {Cannot use '%W' or '%U' without day and year}

Comment: Yes. Correct.  Just made adjustments to solution.

Comment: I'm still having this error: Cannot use '%W' or '%U' without day and year

Comment: Lemme know if this can be fixed

Comment: @EishaTirRaazia Okay... just got time to test and update.  Added 0 to set day of week to Sunday of that week.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

`df["Year-Week"] = df.Year.astype(str).str.cat(df.Week.astype(str), sep="-")`